# Having information on an activity update every time the activity is opened?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Imagine I am in activity 1 and I have a variable x=6 that I display on textView. I display it on textView in my onCreate method. In activity 2, I make x = 5. Then, I switch back to activity1. The textview will still read x = 6. I understand that I could solve this using Intents, but I'm going to be doing similar things throughout my whole app, so I was wondering if there is an easier way - perhaps a method that updates values every time the activity is opened?

Thanks.

EDIT: Also, could I refresh each activity each time the back button on a phone is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a seperate file where you declare your variables as `static` and then read from that file throughout your app for all variables. this is not a great solution, but for your scenario it is the simplest/easiest.

> Also, could I refresh each activity each time the back button on a phone is pressed?

yes, put your update code in `OnResume` (it's an override function)

Comment: consider marking as an answer if it helped, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

override `onResume` method of your Activity class to update your text view